# How to set a property only in the Flutter package, but not in the parent application

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin

My flutter package uses dataBinding. But it only works if my example application has it in the config

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

Is it possible to set this property only inside the build.gradle file of flutter android package? My app doesn't compile unless I set it in example/android/build.gradle

Exactly the same situation with proguard android rules